# Unable to check for variable not found in object arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using advance for loop to loop out all my object in my arraylist which consist of 2 data such as username and password.

The objective is to allow user to edit information. Firstly, i loop using the advance for loop Then i use a condition check if the object in arraylist is the one that the user wants to check. Here's how i implement,

```
String name = Keyboard.readString("Input login name to edit : ");

for(Player p : pData)
    {   
        if(name.equals(p.getLoginName()))
        {
            System.out.println("1. Login Name");
            System.out.println("2. Password");                  
            int option = Keyboard.readInt("Select the option to edit ");

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1 : String newLogin = Keyboard.readString("New Login Name");
                         p.setLoginName(newLogin);
                         System.out.println("Change successful");
                         break;
                case 2 : String newPW = Keyboard.readString("New Password");
                         p.setPassword(newPW);
                         break;
                    default : System.out.println("Wrong option !");
                                continue;
                }
            }
        }               

}
```

I'm able to change the information, however i got a problem where i'm not able to check if the name that the user entered can be found in the object arraylist and i've source all over the net for any snippet but can't seems to find any. I tried using iterator but iterator does not provide such needs. I can't put an if condition in the for loop as it will "triggered" if the first object does not contain such info.

Comment: p.IndexOf(newLogin)

Comment: what i can get from this is the index, but i'm not able to check if the name entered by the user exist in all the object array list.

Comment: I think, here, you can't avoid iterating over all objects to find if the name already exists. One other - but not so clean - approach might be storing the names in some additional data structure.

Comment: From my understanding, your problem is that your don't have a way to confirm that the username that the user enters actually exists, right?

Comment: @NicholasGreene yes you're right.

Comment: You can try `Boolean isUserNamePresent = pData.stream()
        .anyMatch(t -> t.getUserName().equals(name));`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store what you have in pData in a different structure if you want a fast lookup of existing user names. You could iterate once though pData and create a HashMap of username to Player e.g. HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when I need to find something of a specific type which can be identified by name in the form of a string (in your case this is the login name), I use a class that I developed a while back. I call it a library and using it will not only max your code cleaner, but also fix your problem.

I have not included the full code of my Library class, only the piece necessary for your use. Feel free to use it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library<E> {
    ArrayList<E> data = new ArrayList<E>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

    public int size() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public boolean contains(String n) {
        return name.contains(n);
    }        

    public int indexOf(String name) {
        return name.indexOf(name);
    }

    public E get(String n) {
        return data.get(name.indexOf(n));
    }

    //returns the object at index i
    public E get(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    public void setName(int i, String n) {
        name.set(i, n);
    }

    public String getName(int i) {
        return name.get(i);
    }

    public void add(String n, E v) {
       name.add(n);
       data.add(v);
    }
}
```

For your use, you would replace pData with a Library and you also wouldn't have any need of your for loop. It would look something like this:

```
Library<Player> pData = new Library<Player>();

String name = Keyboard.readString("Input login name to edit : ");
if(pData.contains(name)) {
    Player p = pData.get(name);
    //edit the login name, password, etc. here
} else {
    System.out.println("Login name does not exist");
}
```

This Library class is simply a structure similar to an ArrayList which you can use to reference objects by using a name in the form of a string, which can vary depending on user input and other stuff, rather than being a set identifier which must be hard coded into your program.

In your case, the user wants to edit the data of a specific object. The way you are trying to do it, the user types in a login name and then you iterate through an array list of Player objects and see if Player.loginName (or whatever your value is) matches the login name the user entered. While this works, it can become very messy and inconvenient as you expand your programming project. It also proves less efficient than other methods.

If you use this Library class, it would make your code much simpler and easier to manage. It is unnecessary to iterate through your array list and check each Player object's value individually. Instead, it would be much easier and much more efficient to simply index the Player objects by their names from the very beginning. That way, instead of having to check each value individually, you can just reference this Library class and it will tell you exactly where to find the specific Player that you need.

This Library class is very similar to a library catalog (hence the name I gave it). In a library catalog, you lookup the book you need and it tells you exactly where to find it. Now imagine walking through the library on your own and checking each book's title and author individually in order to find what you need. It would be much more difficult and less efficient than simply using the catalog. This is effectively what this Library class accomplishes for you.

To implement it, you wouldn't need to change any of the code regarding the Player or anything like that. Yes, you may have the login name already defined in the Player object, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it can't be defined in a second place. Sometimes it's even a good idea to have multiple places to reference the same value. The only thing that changes is how you add to the Library, as opposed to the ArrayList. You just need to define a name for the object. In your case, this would look something like this:

```
Player p = new Player(); //or whatever you do to construct a player
//do whatever you do to the Player objects here that you normally would before adding them to the array
pData.add(p.loginName, p);

Then when you look for the player you need, simply:

Player p = pData.get(name); //name being the string input from the user
```

Also, when you change the login name of the Player, you must also update its entry in the Library (please note that this only needs to be done when the login name, as the password and other data does not affect the entry in the Library). This would look like this:

```
//code to change login name of the player
//please note that oName is the original login name of the player before it was modified, NOT the new login name
int i = pData.indexOf(oName); //index of the player that was just modified
pData.setName(i, p.loginName); //p is the Player object
```

Comment: I already do have a player class where i store all the getter setter as well as the variable and use them as an object to store in the arraylist. So i'm a little confused on how to integrate them together.

Comment: I guess I can understand why this may be a little confusing. I can update the answer.